# How to vertically stack two panda dataframes on top of each other while keeping their separate columns name?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that have two columns. The first is: "Date" and "X", and the second is "Date" and "Y". Essentially I am trying to create a single panda dataframe to export to excel. I want to stack both those rows/cols on top of each other but maintain their induvial column names. I also need two rows as a separator of the two separate columns, not sure if I have achieved that in the following code.

Here is my code:

```
# Creating an empty dataframe as a seperator
df0  = pd.DataFrame()
df0[''] = ''


df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(x4)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(y1)
df6 = pd.DataFrame(y2)
df7 = pd.DataFrame(y3)
df8 = pd.DataFrame(y4)


df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df0, df2, df0, df3, df0, df4], axis=1)

# This creates an empty row, then the next df will be stacked underneath it
df_merged.append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True)

df_merged2 = pd.concat([df5, df0, df6, df0, df7, df0, df8])


vertical_stack = pd.concat([df_merged,df_merged2]).sort_index()
```

I dont know if this is important, but here is how I am saving it to excel:

```
out_path = "C:\\Users\\JohnReese\\Desktop\\G_Trends\\G_Trend.xlsx"

vertical_stack.to_excel(out_path, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1') 

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd', datetime_format='yyyy-mm-dd')

vertical_stack.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book

worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

worksheet.set_column(0, 10, 30)
writer.save()
```

Desired output in pandas/excel should look like this:

```
Date        | X 
2020-01-01  | 45
(two blank rows here)
Date        | Y
2020-05-18  | 22
```

And with the previous code here is my actual output:

```
Date         | X      Date         | Y
2020-01-01   | 45     2020-05-18   | 22
```

And have been getting the error: ValueError: Plan shapes are not aligned

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: depending on how much coding it is, you can write dataframes to certain cells in excel. then you don't have to concatenate them. or insert the columns of each dataframe as the first row and when you concanate them, the headers will be part of the data, not headers. When you write to excel, don't write the headers as it's not needed

Comment: @JonathanLeon Sorry for the late reply. That's what I ended up doing. I made three separate csv files, the first two were the as described df's then I made a blank row df and created another csv from that. Then concatenated them separately into a single csv with the blank row in the middle, then converted to excel.